# UNIX alarm() with higher granularity

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I am using the UNIX `alarm` system call to deliver a signal to the currently running process on a schedule.

The man page describes the argument to this function as being in units of seconds. I would like to have precision in milliseconds.

Is there an alternative system call on UNIX (or Linux specifically) that will allow this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [setitimer](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setitimer.2.html)() or the more modern (and more flexible) [timer_setitime](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html)() APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straight shell call possible, the perl module Time::HiRes allows this and there's the 3 argument perl select call, is it possible you could write a script to do it?